# Why does one C# application have a limit of '6' WebBrowser pages with sockets.io? How to increase it?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Whenever I use the `WebBrowser` component in a single C# WinForms application more than 6 times (7, 8, ...) all next pages cannot execute javascript properly (to be exact, sockets.io).

When I launch my application twice I can open a total of 12 pages (6 per app). Three times 6 is 18.. and so on. But why can't C# offer more than 6 pages at the same time in one C# application? When the 6th page is opened and sockets.io is being used by JavaScript the `WebBrowser` component shows javascript execution errors, and asks if I want to continue.

Note, I have nothing to do with the website that is being accessed by my application. The website can be any website, but on socket.io websites this happens.

How can I fix this?

Example code:

```
List<WebBrowser> browsers;
browsers = new List<WebBrowser>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browsers.Add(browser);
    browser.Navigate("http://some.website-that-uses-sockets.io/");
    //show in tabs control or anything as new browser tabs
}
```

When running this on websites that initiate a sockets.io connection, after the 6th page has been succesfully loaded, sockets.io won't work anymore. But it will if you limit the maximum pages with sockets.io to 6 per single application it works, making a total of more than 6? Why is this?

I'm experiencing this on Windows 10 x64 with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6 if this matters.

I tried to open the website in 10 tabs on IE. It works fine.